# PHp fsockopen() communicating via Telnet

Tags: php, telnet, fsockopen

I'm looking for a guide on how to use [fsockopen()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fsockopen.php) to communicate with a telnet system.... I'm connected just fine, but the command is failing to send.  I've seen some documentation `fwrite()` that shows people sending some headers.

Currently the command I'm running against the telnet server is `version` via `$class->send("version");`.  Do I need to send headers or anything along with this for the telnet server to pick up the command, or can I just send that?

```
/**
 * Connect to the GMC telnet system
 */
public function connect () {
    $this->connection = fsockopen($this->socket['host'], $this->socket['port'], $errorNumber, $errorMessage, 30);
    if (!$this->connection) {
        $this->error = 'Unable to connect to GMC: '.$errorMessage.' ('.$errorNumber.')';
        return false;
    }
    stream_set_timeout($this->connection, $this->commandTimeout);
    return true;
}

/**
 * Send a command to GMC
 */
public function send ($command) {
    //write to socket
    if (fwrite($this->connection, $command) === false) {
        $this->error = 'Unable to write to socket';
        return false;
    }

    sleep(1);

    //read socket
    if (($response = fgets($this->connection)) === false) {
        $this->error = 'Unable to write to socket';
        return false;
    }

    return $response;
}

/**
 * Disconnects from the GMC telnet system
 */
public function disconnect () {
    return fclose($this->connection);
}
```

Comment: A telnet server implies that you're using a remote shell account... have you done the login process for that? You can't just connect to telnet and starting issuing commands - it'd be expecting a username/password first before getting to the shell stage.

Comment: I connected to the telnet via my local machine, it didn't ask for a username or password.  This is on a local only server that no users ever connect to, only applications.

Comment: even if it's just on your machine, a telnet port is there to do logins. the first things you should send are are a username/password, WITH `\n` to indicate that you've finished typing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently all I needed to do was be sure I included a `\n` at the end of my command!!